# Mysql Getting last entry in Group By

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hey this is my MySQL query

```
$userid="id of logged in user";
```

---

```
SELECT id, MAX( post_time ) , message, user_name, receiver_id, sender_id
FROM chat
WHERE receiver_id =$userid
OR sender_id =$userid
GROUP BY GREATEST( receiver_id, sender_id ) , LEAST( receiver_id, sender_id ) 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 1000
```

it gives the first message recorded between two user not the last. As i want last message to show in message inbox. I use this query to show unique conversations in inbox with different users of a logged in user(or u can say particular user)
You can check demo @ http://www.funnenjoy.com/home

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this code solved by me............. If any one need it will help others also thankyou

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM (
SELECT sender_id + receiver_id -1 AS other_recipient_id, MAX( id ) AS id
FROM chat
WHERE (sender_id =*user's_id*
OR receiver_id =*user's_id*)
GROUP BY sender_id + receiver_id -1
)mm
INNER JOIN chat m ON mm.id = m.id
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT id, message, user_name, receiver_id, sender_id
FROM chat
WHERE post_time = MAX(post_time) AND (receiver_id =$userid
OR sender_id =$userid)
GROUP BY GREATEST( receiver_id, sender_id ) , LEAST( receiver_id, sender_id ) 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 1000
```

Comment: thanks for reply but your code is either wrong or either not working for me. Sorry..............

Comment: I have posted new answer. That may help you

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
SELECT id, message, user_name, receiver_id, sender_id
FROM chat
WHERE receiver_id =$userid
OR sender_id =$userid
HAVING post_time = MAX(post_time) 
GROUP BY GREATEST( receiver_id, sender_id ) ,         LEAST( receiver_id, sender_id ) 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 1000
```

Comment: It gives following error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR sender_id = HAVING post_time = MAX(post_time) GROUP BY GREATEST( receiver_' at line 4`

Comment: just write the "HAVING" clause after "GROUP BY" and then try it

Comment: hey this return the conversation in which only one message is sended sorry........ :)